# Why mapStateToProps return empty object when state has been mutated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-admin

I create action

```
export const KIDS_LOAD = 'KIDS_LOAD';
export const kidsLoad = (data) => ({
    type: KIDS_LOAD,
    payload: data ,
});
```

I create reducer

```
import { KIDS_LOAD } from '../customActions/KidsActions';

export default (state = {}, { type, payload }) => {
    if (type === KIDS_LOAD) {
                return {    ...state,   
                    img: payload.img,
                    kidsInfo: payload.kidsInfo
                };
    }
    return state;
}
```

I dispatch action

```
componentWillMount() {
                this.props.setSidebarVisibility(true);
                const { kidsLoad, record } = this.props;

                kidsLoad({
                    img : 'https://s18670.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/care_about_grades_middle_school.jpg',
                    kidsInfo: {
                        kidName : 'Sasha',
                        kidAge : '19',
                        kidHandType : 'Right',
                        kidGender : 'Boy', 
                    }
                })

                console.log( this.props.kidsTabData)

        }
```

I map state

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        kidsTabData: state.kidsReducer,
        isLoading: state.admin.loading > 0,
    });
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setSidebarVisibility, kidsLoad })(withStyles(styles)(MyLayout));
```

Store mutated
[image]

But console.log( this.props.kidsTabData) return empty object {}.

[image]

Can you tell where I’m wrong? It seems to me that everything goes to the store correctly, but the initialState gets to props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redux action `kidsLoad` is asynchronous.
Try the console.log in `componentDidUpdate`

```
componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log(this.props.kidsTabData)
}
```